# TrailHead EmailManager Apex Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class, trailhead

I am using the EmailManager provided in Trailhead and I am writing a test class and it works as expected (and I get over 75% coverage) but I can't seem to get it to 100% coverage because of the `sendResult = False` in the EmailManager Class.  How can I set up the test class to get 100% coverage?

### EmailManager

```
public class EmailManager
{
   public static void sendMail(String address, String subject, String body) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {address};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject(subject);
        mail.setPlainTextBody(body);
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(
                                 new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

        inspectResults(results);
    }
    private static Boolean inspectResults(Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results) {
        Boolean sendResult = true;

        for (Messaging.SendEmailResult res : results) {
            if (res.isSuccess()) {
                System.debug('Email sent successfully');
            }
            else {
                sendResult = false;
                System.debug('The following errors occurred: ' + res.getErrors());                 
            }
        }
         return sendResult;
    }
}
```

### Test

```
@IsTest
Private class EmailManager_Test
{
    static string address;
    static string subject;
    static string body;
    static boolean sendResult;

    static void init()
    {
       address = 'noreply@email.com';
       subject = 'Test Email for Test Class';
       body = 'This is a Test Email for Test Class';
    }

    public static testMethod void Test_sendMail()
    {
        init();
        test.startTest();    
        EmailManager.sendMail(address, subject, body);
        test.StopTest(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Try a new test method where you pass null as the address and/or subject/body. The email system should fail if the address is null or not valid which theoretically could cause what you're looking for. It could also just throw an exception though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  When I do that it does not like the true side of the equation.   I was curious if there is a way to test for both conditions in one test.  I thought there was a way to do it but I could not make it happen.

Comment: You can not achieve that in this code sample. `sendMail()` is supposed to create only one instance of SingleEmailMessage. Generally, you should prefer that each test method tests a single logical outcome. _Email was send successfully_ would be the first logical outcome, _Errors occurred_ would be the second one.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  At least I know I am not the only one that could not solve since it seems unsolvable.  However, I know this community has many bright people and thought I would see if anyone had a solution or even a creative one.  I was originally only going to accept an answer if could get it too 100% but I reasonable answer is also one where it can't be solved.  If you repost you answer I will be happy to accept.

Comment: @Daryn ,  the trick to effective test is to cover all code paths.
If you cannot cover with a single method, Test_sendMail(), you create another test method for an uncovered path.
In your case, you can have one more failing address variable which is set to a null or invalid address and call sendMail() twice once with a valid email address and another with invalid. Once with a valid address and once with an invalid in the same test.
However, it's not reusable software work. Recommend think of each test to cover a logical unit/path of your work. An effective way is to create more test methods.